# How to show top ten memory consuming processes with ps?

Tags: memory-usage, ps

As stated in the question I want to list the top ten process in my ubuntu which consumes more memory

I am using `ps aux --sort -rss` which sorts based on memory consumption. As the number of processes in my ubuntu is more, I want to limit it to 10.

I've tried `head -10 | ps aux --sort -rss` as well. This displays all processes as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To show top 10 memory consuming processes:

```
ps aux --sort -rss | head -11
```

or:

```
ps aux --sort +rss | tail -10
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do the following:

`ps aux --sort -%mem | head --lines=11`

Comment: That is if you only want the first ten *lines* of sorted output.  Which is not *exactly* the same thing as listing the top ten *processes*.  Try it out to see why the other answer is correct.

Comment: You are right, thats because the first line contains PID, TTY , TIME, CMD, right? so it should be `head  --lines=11´ instead of 10